# swift - invalid_credentials error while firebase facebook authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what caused this problem, FB Login using Firebase was works perfectly. But now I encounter with **INVALID_CREDENTIALS** below error.

I tried deleting app from facebook and again run, and then checking https://developers.facebook.com/ every section but same problem still continue.

This error comes with **print("yes (error)")** line after printing **accessToken** perfectly.

I have searched, but I couldn't find possible solution, why this problem occur, how can I fix it?

**Error Domain=FirebaseAuthentication Code=-11 "(Error Code: INVALID_CREDENTIALS) Invalid authentication credentials provided." UserInfo={details={"providerErrorInfo":{}}, NSLocalizedDescription=(Error Code: INVALID_CREDENTIALS) Invalid authentication credentials provided.}**

```
@IBAction func loginFb_clicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()


    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) in

        if facebookError == nil {

            if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil {

                print("FOUND NIL!")

            }
            else if(facebookResult.isCancelled) {

                print("Cancelled")

            }
            else {

                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                print(accessToken)

                DataService.ds.REF_BASE.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: {
                    error, authData in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("yes \(error)")
                    }
                    else {

                        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"
                        let stringDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
                        print("createdAt: " + stringDate)

                        let user =
                            ["id": authData.providerData["id"] as! String,
                                "accessToken": authData.providerData["accessToken"] as! String,
                                "provider": authData.provider!,
                                "displayName": authData.providerData["displayName"] as! String,
                                "email": authData.providerData["email"] as! String,
                                "profileImageURL": authData.providerData["profileImageURL"] as! String,
                                "token": authData.token as String,
                                "createdAt": stringDate]


                        let uuidString:String = authData.providerData["id"] as! String
                        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath("facebook:"+uuidString)
                            .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                                print("Solved snapshot is:")
                                print(snapshot.value)
                                if !snapshot.exists() {
                                    print("USER NOT EXIST ON DB!")

                                    // DataService.ds.REF_USERS_KEY.childByAppendingPath("facebook:"+uuidString).setValue("1")
                                    DataService.ds.createFirebaseUser(authData.uid, user: user)

                                }
                                else {
                                    print("USER EXIST ALREADY......................")
                                    DataService.ds.REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath("facebook:"+uuidString).updateChildValues(user)
                                }
                            })


                        print("Successfully logged in with facebook. \(accessToken)")
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")

                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: KEY_UID)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_LOGGED_IN, sender: nil)
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that  DataService.ds.REF_BASE is a valid Firebase reference?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem. Even I got accessToken inside this scope. This error happened immediately. All of lines was work well before.

Comment: Note sure if the token being passed into authWithOAuthProvider() is invalid, or if it's the credentials passed into FBSDKLoginManager(). Can you get the stack trace and verify where the error occurs? How are you validating that the token is valid? Does it work if you try to authenticate directly with the SDK using the token? Version info?

Comment: accessToken doesn't pass authWithOAuthProvider(), so error != nil getting this invalid_credentials error. FB ios sdk new downloaded on fb developers page. I have accessToken, but cannot be passed ..OAuthProvider(), Is there any way checking my token valid or not?

Comment: I find that error caused adding white list IP by my friend on facebook app panel. Why does it affect ios connection problem I don't know. I removed and connected with fb without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occured with adding **White IP List** in advanced settings from developer.facebook.com. Check your settings, if you believe you didn't add it, delete. It would be solved.

Comment: Can you be more specific